# PPTPD server with radius auth

Tags: radius, freeradius, pppd

I setup PPTP server based on Debian. I test it using standard pap-secrets file and itu work as expected.

I try to use radius as it's AAA. First I can not fine any /etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf

So I download the radius client source from freeRadius git. compie and make a test

First I got this error :

> Jan 7 04:56:39 core pppd[32761]:
>   /usr/local/etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf: line 81: unrecognized
>   keyword: radius_deadtime Jan 7 04:56:39 core pppd[32761]:
>   /usr/local/etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf: seqfile not specified
>   Jan 7 04:56:39 core pppd[32761]: sent [PAP AuthNak id=0x84 "RADIUS:
>   Can't read config file /usr/local/etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf"]

So I comented the 'radius_deadtime' line, and add line :

Re-test, and got following error:

> Jan 7 05:00:41 core pppd[386]: rc_read_dictionary: invalid type on
>   line 121 of dictionary /usr/local/etc/radiusclient/dictionary Jan 7
>   05:00:41 core pppd[386]: sent [PAP AuthNak id=0x89 "RADIUS: Can't read
>   dictionary file /usr/local/etc/radiusclient/dictionary"]

I check what is in that line 121, and it says :

> ATTRIBUTE Framed-IPv6-Prefix 97 ipv6prefix

Kindly please give me some clue how to fix this.